# Upgrade dependencies that are using the invalid package versions fail

Tags: react-native, expo

when i run npx expo-doctor in my ternimal i get this message:

✔ Check package.json for common issues

✔ Validate global prerequisites versions

✔ Validate Expo Config

✔ Check for incompatible packages

✔ Check for conflicting global packages in project

✔ Check compatible dependency versions for the installed Expo SDK

✖ Verify prebuild support package versions are compatible

```
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~7.8.0
Found invalid:
  @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
  (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
Expected package @expo/prebuild-config@~6.7.0
Found invalid:
  @expo/prebuild-config@5.0.7
  (for more info, run: npm why @expo/prebuild-config)
Advice: Upgrade dependencies that are using the invalid package versions.
```

the truth is that i have installed the packages that they said were invalid with the correct versoin but anytime i run expo doctor it still gives me this message, what do i do

Comment: verify the actual version of those packages by doing `npm list @expo/config-plugins
npm list @expo/prebuild-config`

Comment: this is what I got:
`├── @expo/config-plugins@7.8.4
├─┬ @expo/prebuild-config@6.7.4
│ ├── @expo/config-plugins@7.8.4 deduped
│ └─┬ @expo/config@8.5.4
│   └── @expo/config-plugins@7.8.4 deduped
├─┬ expo-splash-screen@0.26.4
│ └── @expo/prebuild-config@6.7.4 deduped
└─┬ expo@50.0.6
  ├─┬ @expo/cli@0.17.5
  │ ├── @expo/config-plugins@7.8.4 deduped
  │ └── @expo/prebuild-config@6.7.4 deduped
  └── @expo/config-plugins@7.8.4 deduped

`

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution for this? The same thing happened to me after executing `npx expo-doctor` :

```
✖ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK
```

Detailed check results:

Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~7.8.0
Found invalid:
@expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
(for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
Expected package @expo/prebuild-config@~6.7.0
Found invalid:
@expo/prebuild-config@5.0.7
(for more info, run: npm why @expo/prebuild-config)
Advice: Upgrade dependencies that are using the invalid package versions.

One or more checks failed, indicating possible issues with the project.

Comment: it looks like its a problem with the current react native version, but i am still looking for a solution, if i see one i'd post it here, please you you find one please post here also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you using expo-app-loading? if used, replace it with expo-splash-screen